# UK Category 4 Road Racing

Tags: racing, fitness

I am seriously considering road racing, I am wondering what level of fitness I should get myself to before considering entering races. I intend to do TT races next year anyhow, but I was wondering what kind of level I would need to be so that I would generally stay in the bunch for the whole of a race.

Sort of answer I am expecting are be able to maintain 30kmh for 1 hour (on your own) or something like that, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kibbee's suggestion is a good one. You should feel comfortable on a fast group ride...one that has a pace range of 35-40 kph. YOu should also be able to handle surges in speed and intervals of speeding up and slowing down. You should feel comfortable in a group of riders. I'm not just talking about being able to ride in a paceline, but also feel comfortable with 5-10 riders in close proximity to you - elbows almost touching, handling corners, etc. Find a moderate roadie group ride and go out with them a few times, you'll soon find if you are cut out for racing or if you need a little practice. Talk with the guys/ladies on the ride and learn all you can. Experience is invaluable.

Fitness is definitely important, but handling skills are often overlooked with new racers. It's both for your safety and the safety of others that you are able to hold a line, know pack etiquette, and are not going to be jumpy or make lots of wild riding or erratic moves.

A common issue with riders coming from the TT world is just that. They are fit enough, but they are used to riding by themselves and not necessarily drafting or riding with several people around them.

Comment: I was wondering if the only way I would get comfortable in a group of riders that close was to race same if that make sense. Thank you for your response.

Comment: You can do a lot of work with just one or two other people to get comfortable in a group. Google "Cycling Bump Drills" or "Cycling handling skills" and you'll get some good ones. Basically you need to be comfortable with someone riding close enough to you that you're not going to drift away or pull away if they rub shoulders/elbows. It goes against your instincts, which is hard but it's well worth it if you are considering racing.

Answer (score 4):

Try to figure out where the local racers do their training.  Ask your local bike store if they operate any training groups and if there are any racers in the group.  Go out with them on training runs to see if you can get a feel for where you stand in terms of fitness.  My LBS has rides once a week, and there are some racers that show up for that, but I don't see much of them after they leave.  I think this would be ideal, because even if you couldn't keep up, you could always hang back with the slower riders and have a good time.

Comment: I currently go on club rides with my local triathlon club and I am pretty much at the back of them, I was wondering in terms of where I am not to where I need to be before I can start racing if that makes sense. The local cycling clubs that race go out the same days as my triathlon club though the tri club is nearer.